# Is possible to filter buckets by prefix using Spring Cloud for AWS?

Tags: amazon-s3, spring-cloud, aws-java-sdk, aws-java-sdk-2.x

I'm trying to use the Spring Cloud for AWS to list my buckets, but I'd like to filter the buckets as LIKE operator.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Version: 2.2.1.RELEASE

```
amazonS3Client.listBuckets();
```

But I'd like to do something like this, but without need to get all buckets and then filter.

```
amazonS3Client.listBuckets().stream().filter(bucket -> bucket.getName().contains("filter-key")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance